# My docker-compose can not run or build, causing issues

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am creating a Django application and now I am creating a docker container for that application. I am using the MySQL database with Django. So after creating my entire project when It was successfully running, I wanted to containerize it. I created the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file. Here is the content of my file.

**Dockerfile**

```bash
FROM python:3.10

ENV DockerHOME=/home/app/webapp
RUN mkdir -p $DockerHOME
WORKDIR $DockerHOME

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . $DockerHOME
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Add Django migrations and apply them
RUN python manage.py makemigrations
RUN python manage.py migrate

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
```

and here is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: blogs:latest
    container_name: blogs_web
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/webapp
    environment:
      - PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}  
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG}  
      - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: data:latest
    container_name: blogs_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

When I run

```bash
docker-compose build
```

it gives me this response

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\Blogs> docker-compose build
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
```

The build isn't right. and when I do

```bash
docker-compose up
```

here is my error

````
(venv) PS C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\Blogs> docker-compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 ✘ web Error                                                                                                         3.8s 
 ✘ db Error                                                                                                          3.8s 
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for blogs, the repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied```
````

I am using Windows. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Your `web` container doesn't have a [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) block, so `docker-compose build` doesn't realize there's anything to build.  I'd also suggest removing the `volumes:` block that overwrites the image's code with a volume mount, and the unnecessary `container_name:` options.

Comment: You could update Python 3.12.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed all the issues, cause I had issues with my docker-compose.yml file.

It resolved all my issues like:

- Not using 'root' user
- Not using 'localhost' as Database_HOST
- Writing a line in Dockerfile to handle static content of the Django application.
- DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD should always be there in docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: blogs_mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /opt/noorblogs/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - /tmp/noorblogs/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "--password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  backend:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: blogs
    command: sh -c "python3 manage.py migrate --noinput && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

and this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/
COPY ./static/ /app/static/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

.env file

```
DATABASE_PASSWORD=*****
DATABASE_USER=mysql
DATABASE_NAME=noorblogs
DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY=*****
DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
```